# How to make the method of sorting by options universal?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wrote a sort method for the options "filterProductBy (options)", tell me how to make this method universal, regardless of the number of parameters, I could apply this filter. Tell me please how to do this?

```js
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    //method for filtering products by specified parameters
    filterProductBy(options) {
        const optionName = options.name,
            optionCount = options.count,
            optionPrice = options.price;

        const filters = {
            byName: optionName == undefined ? () => undefined :
                (actualName, optionName) => actualName === optionName,

            byCount: optionCount == undefined ? () => undefined :
                new Function("actualName, optionName", "return actualName " + optionCount),

            byPrice: optionPrice == undefined ? () => undefined :
                new Function("actualName, optionName", "return actualName " + optionPrice)
        };
        return this.products.filter(
            (product) => filters.byName(product.name, optionName)
            || filters.byCount(product.count, optionCount)
            || filters.byPrice(product.price, optionPrice));
    }
}
const shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("item 2", 2, 100));
shop.addProduct(new Product("some 3", 30, 300));
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "product 1",
    count: ">=4",
    price: ">500"
}));
```

Comment: "sort" != "filter"

Comment: What does universal mean here? I'm sorry I do not understand pretty well the question.

Comment: it is already universal

Comment: What is `new Function("actualName, optionName", "return actualName " + optionCount)` supposed to do? If `optionCount` is just a number or something, that's a syntax error (within the `new Function` call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be nearly that complicated. Just loop through the properties of the object you get, and include an item if it matches any of them (since your filter is an "OR" filter):

```
filterProductBy(options) {
    var keys = Object.keys(options);
    return this.products.filter(product => keys.some(key => product[key] == options[key]));
}
```

If `==` doesn't work for all the options, you'd use a `switch` on `key` (in the `some` callback) to pick the right relation to use.

Live Example:

```js
var products = [
  {name: "Widget", count: 12, price: 100},
  {name: "Gadget", count: 2, price: 70},
  {name: "Thingy", count: 14, price: 80}
];

function filterProductBy(options) {
    var keys = Object.keys(options);
    return this.products.filter(product => keys.some(key => product[key] == options[key]));
}

console.log("name: Widget", filterProductBy({name: "Widget"}));
console.log("name: Widget, count: 2", filterProductBy({name: "Widget", count: 2}));
```

That gets the keys of `options` as an array, then uses those in the `filter` callback to see if the product matches any of them by using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

If you wanted an "AND" filter instead, you'd use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of `some`:

```
filterProductBy(options) {
    var keys = Object.keys(options);
    return this.products.filter(product => keys.every(key => product[key] == options[key]));
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var products = [
  {name: "Widget", count: 12, price: 100},
  {name: "Gadget", count: 2, price: 70},
  {name: "Thingy", count: 14, price: 80}
];

function filterProductBy(options) {
    var keys = Object.keys(options);
    return this.products.filter(product => keys.every(key => product[key] == options[key]));
}

console.log("name: Widget", filterProductBy({name: "Widget"}));
console.log("name: Widget, count: 14", filterProductBy({name: "Widget", count: 14}));
console.log("name: Thingy, count: 14", filterProductBy({name: "Thingy", count: 14}));
```